# how to make html form to send email in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter and making one form which send the all details to mail.
But i didn't get the solution and my form is not working.
here is my view file in view

```
contact_us in view
<?php 
        $form=array('class'=>'contact-form default-form','id'=>'myform');
        echo form_open('success_form/success',$form);
        ?>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="preamble col-md-12">
              <h3>Get in touch</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $name=array('placeholder'=>'Name','name'=>'name');
            echo form_input($name);
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $company=array('placeholder'=>'company','name'=>'company');
            echo form_input($company);

            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $number=array('placeholder'=>'Phone Number','name'=>'number');
            echo form_input($number);
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $email=array('placeholder'=>'Email','name'=>'email');
            echo form_input($email);
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="arrival calendar">
            <?php
            $arrival=array('name'=>'arrival','placeholder'=>'Arrival','data-dateformat'=>'m/d/y');
            echo form_input($arrival);
            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="departure calendar">
            <?php
            $departure=array('name'=>'departure','placeholder'=>'Departure','data-dateformat'=>'m/d/y');
            echo form_input($arrival);
            ?>
               <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <span class="select-box" title="hotel-type">
              <select name="person" data-placeholder="Number of People">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="10+">10+</option>
              </select>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea placeholder="How we can help you"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-md text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-transparent-white">Send Message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php echo form_close();?>
```

here is my controller file
success_form in controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Success_form extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    }

    public function index(){

        // Set Validation Rule

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company','Company','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('number','Mobile Number','required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('arrival','Arrival','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('departure','Departure','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('person','Number of Person','trim|required|xss_clean|numeric');


    //Run Validation on Form Input

    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
     // Validation fails
        $this->load->view('contact_us_view');
    }
    else{
        // get the form data
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $company=$this->input->post('company');
        $number=$this->input->post('number');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $arrival=$this->input->post('arrival');
        $departure=$this->input->post('departure');
        $person=$this->input->post('person');

        //Set email id
        $to_email='aziz.khan@vklalco.com';

        //configure email settings
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
            //$this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->initialize($config);

             //send mail
            $this->email->from($email, $name);
            $this->email->to('$to_email');
            $this->email->subject('testing mail');
            $this->email->message('content');

            if($this->email->send()){
                //mail sent
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
                redirect('success_form/index');
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
                redirect('success_form/index');
            }
    }
  }

   //custom validation function to accept only alphabets and space input
    function alpha_space_only($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    function success(){
        $this->load->view('success_view');
    }

}
```

I tried lot but did'nt get the answer.please help me to find the solution ..

Comment: try this link: http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-gmail-smtp/

Comment: suyog ..I tried same but not working ..please see my code

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: It successfully redirect to success page .but all details are not going to mail

Comment: 'but all details are not going to mail' - what does this mean? the form is sending mail but not the details OR the form is not at all sending the mail OR do you receive any error message OR anything else?

Comment: I am not getting any error it redirect to success page but i want when any one fill the form and click on submit button so all content of form need to send in given email id .

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are submitting form to success action of success_form controller.

> echo form_open('success_form/success',$form);

In your success action you are again loading the same form.

> function success(){
>           $this->load->view('success_view');
>       }

You have written your send mail logic in index action which you need to call in success action to send email.

```
function success(){
        $this->index();
        $this->load->view('success_view');
    }
```

This might work for you.